# How to use 'LIKE' in python sql query

Tags: python, sql, binding, wildcard

How to use '?' wildcard ?

```
nome ="test"
cursor = db.execute("SELECT id FROM marca WHERE nome LIKE ?",('%'+nome))
```

Thank

Comment: The `?` is a parameter marker, the `%` is the wildcard.

Comment: @ruohola, which dbms has `?` for single character?!? ANSI/ISO SQL has `_`, underscore.

Comment: @jarlh Ah :D only MS Access :DDDDD

Comment: I searched for it before to ask , Thanks . Link useful. I want just ask what ':s' means here `pattern = "%"+nome+"%"   cursor = db.execute("SELECT id FROM marca WHERE nome like :s",{"s":pattern})`